# Accessing EFS file system from Fargate ECS task - Not working without any kind of error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I tried to connect an EFS file system to an ECS Fargate Task, based on the examples in the documentation. I cannot write to the volume (sadly I cannot change the container in a way to report if it can write from there)

The task is provisioned without any error, but the starting container cannot write into the mounted volume.

In contrast to some other questions here, I do NOT get any error message from AWS. Just the container reporting an AccessDeniedException.

I am running out of ideas how to troubleshoot this.

- Both EFS and the ECS task run within the same security group
- The security group has an inbound rule allowing traffic between all nodes in the group
- Another inbound rule for NFS has been added explicitly just in case
- I tried anonymous access as well as access point IAM role-based access
- I tried a file system policy granting mount and read to anyone as well as the IAM role from above

Whatever I change in the configuration, the behaviour stays the same. When I add erros to the filesystem ID or access point ID those are catched however, so the console thinks the configuration is fine.

I can see client connects for the file system in CloudWatch, however I do not see if those are successful or not. Does that mean networking is fine, but access permissions are wrong?

Task config:

```
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "controlserver-files",
                    "containerPath": "/application/files",
                    "readOnly": false
                }
            ],
```

```
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "controlserver-files",
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "fileSystemId": "fs-99999999999",
                "rootDirectory": "/",
                "transitEncryption": "ENABLED"
            }
        }
    ],
```

File system policy:

```
        {
            "Sid": "efs-statement-08270b77-b8c4-4788-b12a-7226fbcc0e21",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:eu-central-1:977555550711:file-system/fs-02bab7777777774"
        }
```

Comment: What is the "file system policy" exactly? Is that part of an IAM role that is assigned to the ECS task? It would need to be in the IAM role assigned as the  ECS Task Role (Not the Execution Role).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look on permissions on the EFS volume itself?
There is this useful blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-2/

I would first start by mounting EFS to ie your local machine or an EC2 instance and check the permissions on the root folder. For testing, you may set the permissions to 777 so that anyone, any UID, can read and write there.

> $ sudo chmod 777 /EFSroot

If this works, I would go and be less permissive. You may check this doc on permissions for NFS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-nfs-permissions.html

Feel free to share the results.

Comment: It actually was the permissions of the root directory. Instead of connecting to it, I used an Access Point and configured it to create its own home directory with the permissions.